# Python3 for-loop even or odd

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Hi i got stuck in an exercise i have in school. and could use some help.

Create a for-loop that goes through the numbers:

```
67,2,12,28,128,15,90,4,579,450
```

If the current number is even, you should add it to a variable and if the
current number is odd, you should subtract it from the variable.

Answer with the final result.

Here is my code so far.

```
def listnum(a):
for num in [67, 2, 12, 28, 128, 15, 90, 4, 579, 450]:
    if (num%2):
        a = a + num
    else:
        a = a - num
    return a
```

ANSWER = a

when i run this program i get the answer:

```
5.6 FAIL.
You said:
4 class 'int'>
```

the correct answer should be `53` if initial value of `a` is `0`.

can any one help me and tell what im doing wrong? 
or maybe point me in the right direction. 
thank you!

Comment: `if(num % 2 == 0)`, 0 is falsy otherwise

Comment: remember, python is white-space dependent, so when you post code, be wary of what you are giving us.

Comment: To be excplicit, @Fallenreaper is saying that your return currently will end your function after the first execution of your else block.

Comment: Thanks for giving further clarification @dckuehn sometimes i forget to get into the weeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make more sense if your function input is the list and not the return value. Also (as others have noted) you need `num % 2 == 0` and your indentation is not quite right. Try this instead:

```
def listSum(l):
  ans = 0
  for num in l:
    if num % 2 == 0:
      ans += num
    else:
      ans -= num
  return ans
```

Note that you could do this in a single line:

```
def listSum(l):
    return sum(i if i % 2 == 0 else -i for i in l)
```

`print(listSum([67, 2, 12, 28, 128, 15, 90, 4, 579, 450]))` prints `53` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to adjust your condition mostly.

```
def listSum(a):
  for num in [67, 2, 12, 28, 128, 15, 90, 4, 579, 450]:
    if(num % 2 == 0):  #subtle difference here.
      a += num
    else:
      a -= num
  return a
```

this will see just a subtle difference.